# ¿Cómo compararo dos fechas en formato iso-8601 en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, date

Quiero comparar dos fechas para saber si tienen una diferencia de 5 o mas días entre ellas. Estas fechas son creadas en la base de dato automáticamente al insertar una nueva fila, es decir, se crear la columna `createdAt` y se le guarda una fecha en este formato: `2021-02-11 01:04:34`.

Según lo que he leído ese es el formato `ISO-8601`. El problema es que esa fecha la necesito comparar con la fecha actual, la cual la podría obtener con `new Date(Date.now());`, pero esto me devuelve una fecha con este formato:
`Thu Feb 11 2021 00:17:11 GMT-0400`

¿Cómo podría hacer para comparar estos dos formatos y obtener la diferencia de días entre ambas? ¿Tendría que obtener la fecha actual de otra forma?

Por más que busco no encuentro la manera aunque parezca muy sencillo. Estoy trabajando con node.js y la base de datos es Mysql con el ORM sequelize. Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar.

Estoy intentando esto:

```js
fechaBaseDeDatos= new Date('2021-02-11 01:04:34').getTime();
console.log(fechaBaseDeDatos)
fechaActual= new Date().getTime();
console.log(fechaActual);

//2 dias = 172800000 milisegundos
```

No entiendo por que la diferencia me da como resultado un valor negativo. Estoy intentando tener ambas fechas en milisegundos y luego comparar si la diferencia entre ambas es mayor a 172800000 (2 dias), pero como comento, no entiendo por qué la diferencia da negativa si se supone que fecha actual siempre será mayor que la otra fecha.

Comment: lo que he intentado es obtener la fecha actual como menciono en mi pregunta, pero al ser de formatos distintos no se como proceder, se que hay una librería llamado moment.js pero la verdad no creo que sea lo mejor bajar una librería solo para esa operación.

Comment: Agrega la comparación que hayas intentado

Comment: @BetaM acabo de agregar lo que he intentado.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de datos se almacena en ese campo de fecha? El formato de salida (ISO-8601) es sólo un formato de presentación del dato almacenado. El tipo de dato es lo que te indicará la forma de trabajar con el mismo. Además supongo que la fecha la obtienes de una consulta a la DB, entonces, ¿esta comparación la quieres hacer en el lado front o en el back? Si es en el `front`, nuevamente es necesario el tipo de dato enviado por el back, pero si es en el back hay que conocer el driver de tu DB usado o la forma en que obtienes dicha información. Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio, esa columna se crea automáticamente al insertar una fila. se crean: de createdAt y updatedAt, sin embargo creo que están en formato string. La comparación la quería hacer en el Back. A qué te refieres con el drivers de la DB? estoy usando MySQL con el ORM Sequelize en node.js.

Comment: @JulianProg `new Date(Date.now())` lo obtienes con JS? Si es asi, lo puedes parsear al formato que quieras

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solucion es mas simple de lo que parece **"parsear la fecha"** ¿Porque? Porque se puede restar dias si estan en el mismo formato

```js
let fecha_bd = new Date('2021-02-10 01:04:34'); //Fecha BD
let fecha_now = new Date(); //Fecha Actual
let diferencia = fecha_now.getDate() - fecha_bd.getDate();
console.log(diferencia);
```

Aunque para el manejo de fechas, te recomiendo usar [moment-js](https://momentjs.com/) ya que es la libreria mas usada para hacer este tipo de cosas y es super util

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Esa creo que es la mejor opcion. Sin embargo, podrías echarle un ojo a la solución que implementé? esta en una de las respuestas,  lo probé y funcionó, pero me gustaría saber la opinión de alguien si no es mucha molestia claro.

Comment: @JulianProg en si es lo mismo que hago, pero tu lo haces con `getTime`. Aunque nose porque se complicaron tanto en hacer esto. Yo solo uso moment y listo, adios problemas jajaj

Comment: Tienes razón, solo que quise hacerlo por mi propia cuenta, me pareció que era muy simple (en un principio), pero luego me costó un poco. Bueno muchas gracias, aceptaré tu respuesta ya que me parece que es la mas sencilla y eficiente de todas.

Answer (score 1):

Logré hacerlo de esta manera, de momento me funciona:

```js
            let fechaActual = new Date();
            fechaActual= fechaActual.getTime(); //fecha actual en milisegundos

            let fechaCompra= new Date(fechaEnFormatoIso-8601); //como está en la base de datos 
            fechaCompra= fechaCompra.getTime();
            if((fechaActual - fechaCompra)>= 432000000){ // resto las fechas y verficio el resultado es mayor a 432000000 (5 dias)
```

Answer (score 0):

En este tipo de situaciones, al menos yo si prefiero apoyarme en una biblioteca de manejo de fechas y tiempos (*es tanto lo que se debe controlar sobre estos 2 temas*)

**Ejemplo**

```
  let fecha = '2021-02-01T00:12:00';
  
  let fechaUno = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(fecha);
  let fechaDos = luxon.DateTime.local();
  
  let res = fechaDos.diff(fechaUno, ['days']).toObject()
```

Para este caso:

- Puedes invocarlo (*a luxon*) desde un CDN
- Obtengo un [*DateTime*](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#static-method-fromISO) a partir de una cadena que se sujete al standar mencionado (el ISO 8601)
- Para obtener la marca de fecha y tiempo actual [hacemos uso de DateTime.local()](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/moment.html#datetime-method-equivalence)
- Posterior para obtener por ejemplo la diferencia entre ambas marcas hacemos uso del [método `diff`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#instance-method-diff)

  - Recomiendo leas a detalle los enlaces de la propia doc. que te estoy referenciando pues por ejemplo si no paso un array de *strings* como segundo argumento entonces la diferencia calculada será en milisegundos (*yo en este caso lo dejé para que muestre la diferencia en días*)

Un ejemplo de la salida calculada en días sería así mas o menos:

```
[object Object] {
  days: 10.009060289351853
}
```

**Enlaces de referencia y fuentes de consulta**

- Documentación de [Luxon.js](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html)
- Esto es un tema muy amplio, [te dejo esta lectura al respecto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Hola Beta, entiendo tu respuesta, si veo que es muy amplio, algo que parece tan simple. edité mi pregunta con una forma que hallé y al parecer me funciona, podrías echarle un ojo y comentarme que te parece? gracias!

Comment: Esa edición debe ir como respuesta y no en la pregunta

Comment: Ya la coloco como respuesta, sin embargo, en base a tu experiencia, podríamos darme tu opinión respecto a esa solución que se me ocurrió?